# What is the distribution of time's to ruin in the gambler's ruin problem (random walk)?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-walk

In a gambler's ruin problem, where the gambler starts with a fixed amount of wealth. What is the distribution of times to ruin. That is, if each bet has a fixed payout.

As I understand it, this is a one dimensional random walk which stops when it hits zero. What is the distribution of steps taken to get to zero?

Comment: Could you explain more about your difficulties? As, e.g., why the solutions provided in textbooks are not sufficient?

Comment: Could you reference a textbook provided solution? I've mostly seen distributions of wealth, but I'm interested in the CDF of the time to ruin which I've not seen.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution#Relationship_with_Brownian_motion (continuous case)

Answer (score 5):

**Time-to-ruin in the discrete-time random walk:** From your question, I take it that you are referring to a discrete-time version of the gambler's ruin problem.  Without loss of generality we can consider the wealth of the gambler denominated in units equivalent to the betting amount.  We will assume that the wealth of the gambler is a positive whole number of such units, and we denote the starting wealth as $w_0 \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then the time-to-ruin is defined as:

$$T \equiv \min \{ t \in \mathbb{N} | w_t = 0 \},$$

where the wealth follows the unit random walk process:

$$w_t = w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^t \Delta_i
\quad \quad \quad \mathbb{P}(\Delta_i = -1) = \mathbb{P}(\Delta_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

The time-to-ruin is the "hitting time" for the state $w=0$ in this stochastic process.  You can determine the distribution of the time-to-ruin by looking at the distributions of the hitting times.  Here it is useful to appeal to a special result for random walks called the "hitting time theorem" (see e.g., [Van Der Hofstad and Keane 2008](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2008.11920588?journalCode=uamm20) and [Kager 2017](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.08.735)), which shows that:

$$\mathbb{P}(T=t) = \frac{w_0}{t} \cdot \mathbb{P}(w_t = 0).$$

Below we will use this result to derive a useful distribution that is closely related to the distribution of the time-to-ruin.  The result is a [discrete phase-type distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_phase-type_distribution), which is a type of distribution used to model the hitting time to the absorbing state of a Markov chain.

---

**Deriving the distribution of the time-to-ruin:** Looking at the nature of the random walk, it is easy to see that the time-to-ruin must occur somewhere over the support $t = w_0, w_0 + 2, w_0 + 4, w_0 + 6, ...$.  This is quite an intuitive result --- we need to have at least $w_0$ bets to lose the starting wealth, and any additional bets leading to ruin must come in pairs, each with one win and one loss cancelling each other out.  Thus, to facilitate our analysis, it is useful to work with the total number of *winning* bets in the time-to-ruin:

$$R \equiv \frac{T - w_0}{2},$$

which has support $r = 0,1,2,3,...$.  Now, applying the hitting time theorem above, we get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(R=r) 
= \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \frac{T - w_0}{2} = r \Bigg) 
&= \mathbb{P} ( T = w_0 + 2r )  \\[6pt]
&= \frac{w_0}{w_0 + 2r} \cdot \mathbb{P} ( w_{w_0 + 2r} = 0 ) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{w_0}{w_0 + 2r} \cdot \mathbb{P} \Bigg( w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{w_0 + 2r} \Delta_i = 0 \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{w_0}{w_0 + 2r} \cdot \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{w_0 + 2r} \mathbb{I}(\Delta_i=1) = r \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{w_0}{w_0 + 2r} \cdot \text{Bin} ( r | w_0 + 2r, \tfrac{1}{2} ) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{w_0}{w_0 + 2r} \cdot \frac{(w_0 + 2r)!}{(w_0+r)! r!} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{w_0 + 2r}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{w_0}{2^{w_0}} \cdot \frac{(w_0 + 2r - 1)!}{(w_0+r)! r!} \cdot \frac{1}{4^r} \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

It is simplest to frame the gambler's ruin problem in terms of this distribution.  However, we can convert back to the distribution for $T$.  For any value $t = w_0, w_0 + 2, w_0 + 4, w_0 + 6, ...$ in the support for the time-to-ruin, we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(T=t) = w_0 \cdot \frac{(t - 1)!}{(\tfrac{t+w_0}{2})! (\tfrac{t-w_0}{2})!} \cdot \frac{1}{2^t}.$$

---

**Implementation in `R`:** We can program this density function using standard syntax for probability distribution as follows.  In this function the input `t` is a vectorised input for the time-to-ruin.  The function produces density values by default, but you can use the `log` input to produce log-densities instead.

```
druintime <- function(t, w, log = FALSE) {
  
  #Check inputs
  if (!is.numeric(t))           { stop('Error: Input t should be numeric') }
  if (!is.numeric(w))           { stop('Error: Input w must be a positive integer') }
  if (length(wealth) != 1)      { stop('Error: Input w must be a single value') }
  if (as.integer(w) != w)       { stop('Error: Input w must be a positive integer') }
  if (min(wealth) < 1)          { stop('Error: Input w must be a positive integer') }
  if (!is.logical(log))         { stop('Error: Input log must be a logical value') }
  if (length(log) != 1)         { stop('Error: Input log must be a single value') }
  
  #Compute number of successes in each time-to-ruin
  #and set indicators for integer values
  n   <- length(t)
  r   <- (t - w)/2
  IND <- (as.integer(r) == r)&(r >= 0)
  
  #Compute log-density
  LOGDEN <- rep(-Inf, n)
  LOGDEN[IND] <- log(w) - log(w + 2*r[IND]) +
                 dbinom(r[IND], size = w + 2*r[IND], prob = 1/2, log = TRUE)
  
  #Give output
  if (log) { LOGDEN } else { exp(LOGDEN) } }
```

Implementing this with starting wealth $w_0 = 6$ gives the following probability mass function.

```
#Compute probability mass function over a set of input values
t    <- 0:200
w0   <- 6
DENS <- druintime(t, w = w0)

#Plot the mass function
t.names <- rep(NA, length(t))
for (i in 0:20) { t.names[1+10*i] <- t[1+10*i] }
barplot(DENS, names.arg = t.names,
        main = 'Probability Mass Function for Time-to-Ruin', col = 'red',
        xlab = 'Time-to-Ruin', ylab = 'Probability')
```

[image]

Comment: great analysis! just a question - how would someone simulate random numbers from a "discrete phase type distribution"?

Comment: @user123945: One method is just to simulate the relevant Markov chain and use a ```while``` loop to get the relevant hitting times.  In some cases it is possible to get the spectral decomposition of the transition probability matrix for the chain and use this to derive an explicit formula for the distribution of the hitting times.  You can find an example of deriving and computing a distribution coming from a Markov chain in [O'Neill (2022)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11009-022-09966-x) and [O'Neill (2023)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11009-023-10053-y).

Comment: can you use the uniform distribution via the probability integral transformation .... and then simulate from this discrete phase type distribution?

Comment: I just tried using acceptance-rejection sampling - is this correct? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/636706/how-to-simulate-random-times-from-gamblers-ruin

Comment: @user123945: There are lots of ways you can potentially undertake your sampling.  To test whether you have programmed it correctly, generate a large sample from your method and compare the empirical distribution of the sample to the probability distribution you are trying to sample from.  With a large sample, the LLN ensures that these two should be close to one another, so if you have made a mistake you will be able to see it.

Comment: I tried to take inspiration from your work and derive the probability distribution of absorption times in markov chains. did I do this correctly? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637986/deriving-the-distribution-of-markov-chain-times

Answer (score 3):

Say your starting wealth is $W(0) = 6$ and we take 20 steps of the random walk, where a gambler has fifty-fifty probability to loose or win 1, then probability distribution for wealth looks like a (scaled and shifted) binomial distribution.

[image: example]

Obviously the cases with $W(20) \leq 0$ have gone bankrupt. But the amount of bankrupt gambler's is larger. Due to the symmetry of the steps — after hitting zero one is as likely to reach a certain positive value as a certain negative value — for every case of a gambler that is at a value below zero, there is an equivalent case that is above zero. To get to know the amount of gamblers that have still positive wealth we need to subtract that part. This is also called [the reflection principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)).

So we can model the cumulative distribution function for bankruptcy after $n=w(0)+2x$ steps as

$$F_{bankrupt}(n) = F_\text{binom}\left(\frac{n-w(0)}{2},n,p=0.5\right) + F_\text{binom}\left(\frac{n-w(0)}{2}-1,n,p=0.5\right)$$

[image: example]

```
n = seq(6,100,2)
yF = pbinom((n-6)/2,n,0.5)+pbinom((n-6)/2-1,n,0.5)
yf = diff(c(0,yF))
plot(n,yf, type = "h", lwd = 3, main = "probability distribution for \n bankruptcy after n steps if w(0)=6", ylab = "probability")
```

Comment: I tried to take inspiration from your work and derive the probability distribution of absorption times in markov chains. did I do this correctly? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637986/deriving-the-distribution-of-markov-chain-times